# Changing visibility is causing my app to crash, why?

Tags: java, android

I have 2 classes. One class has created my maze game in my GameView class which extends View. The GameView class :  sets my view's visibility to be VISIBLE until player == exit, then it goes invisible (as intended) but my LinearLayout view (which is INVISIBLE OnCreate, MainActivity.java) which is set to go VISIBLE when the boolean (player == exit) is true, causes for the app to crash.

I know changing the LinearLayout's visiblity is causing the crash as if I comment it out, it crashes the app. I've tried to change the visibility's in my MainActivity class but that doesn't seem to be working either.

I'm currently trying to use Intent to push this information to the MainActivity, to use my playAgain() but I'm not sure how to do it.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        LinearLayout layout = findViewById(R.id.playAgainLayout);
        layout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}

public void createMaze(){
...
...
 do {
            next = getNeighbour(current);
            if (next != null) {
                removeWall(current, next);
                stack.push(current);
                current = next;
                current.visited = true;
            } else
                current = stack.pop(); //gives us the top element of the stack and removes it from the
        }while(!stack.empty());

        Animation slideUp = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(), R.anim.slide_up);
        gameView.startAnimation(slideUp);
}

public void checkExit() {
        if (player == exit && counter < 3) {
            counter++;

            Animation slideDown = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(), R.anim.mazeslidedown);
            gameView.startAnimation(slideDown);
            gameView.setVisibility(INVISIBLE);

//            layout.setVisibility(VISIBLE);

        }
    }
```

What I want is for the maze to go INVISIBLE, the LinearLayout to become VISIBLE and allow for the user to be able to tap my button (to restart the maze,  for now).

Stack Trace(?):

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.practicingandroidwithsean.mazeone, PID: 1319
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.LinearLayout.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.practicingandroidwithsean.mazeone.GameView.checkExit(GameView.java:286)
        at com.example.practicingandroidwithsean.mazeone.GameView.movePlayer(GameView.java:274)
        at com.example.practicingandroidwithsean.mazeone.GameView.onTouchEvent(GameView.java:341)
        at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:12540)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3159)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2844)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3159)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2844)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3159)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2844)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3159)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2844)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3159)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2844)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3159)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2844)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:601)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1871)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:3384)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:69)
        at com.android.tools.profiler.support.event.WindowProfilerCallback.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowProfilerCallback.java:69)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:563)
        at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:12788)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5670)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:5465)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4958)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:5011)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4977)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:5114)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4985)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:5171)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4958)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:5011)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4977)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4985)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4958)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7736)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:7676)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7637)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7847)
        at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:197)
        at android.view.InputEventReceiver.nativeConsumeBatchedInputEvents(Native Method)
        at android.view.InputEventReceiver.consumeBatchedInputEvents(InputEventReceiver.java:186)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doConsumeBatchedInput(ViewRootImpl.java:7810)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ConsumeBatchedInputRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7874)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:911)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:723)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:652)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:897)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6944)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
Application terminated.
```

Comment: Post your stack trace if its a crash

Comment: Although this is almost certainly a null pointer error-  you aren't setting a variable called layout anywhere. It looks like you do in onCreate, but that sets a local variable, not a class variable.

Comment: I've set LinearLayout layout; with the rest of my class variables. I'll post stack trace in a few moments

Comment: But you also defined LinearLayout layout in onCreate.  That created a local variable, so when you assigned layout you assigned it to the locally scoped variable and not the class scoped variable.  So your class scoped layout was never initialized

Comment: I'll try changing that around now. Stack trace posted

Comment: Yeah, stack trace pretty much confirms its what I though.  Just delete the words LinearLayout before layout=

Comment: Delete the words LinearLayout where? In my onCreate?

Comment: Yes.  If you have a layout variable at class scope that recreation of the same variable name is hiding it with a locally scoped version.  Removing the type from that line will cause it to assign to the class scoped variable instead.

Comment: The OnCreate method is inside of my MainActivity, whereas, the rest of my code 'createMaze()' and 'checkExit()' is inside of my GameView. If I remove the LinearLayout it just flags the code in red

Comment: has this question been answered yet @SeanO

Comment: @a_local_nobody no answers were specific to the problem I was having. I couldn't get rid of the error without making my gameView static. This has lead to warning of a 'memory leak'. I've experienced this leak throughout my app, but applied a bit of common sense to get around it, although its unfortunate its happening. You can't see it from what I've posted (because the post would be too large), but I have defined my gameView, and the problem continued to persist until made static

Comment: why did you have to make it static ?

Comment: so that it wouldn't point a null pointer reference (according to Android Studio) haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen your other post about that, and think that the problem is because you try to acces a layout object that is not related with that class, you can do it in your main class on your onCreate() by using setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); to asociate it and send it via reference on your other class, but I'm not sure that with passing it is going to work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot `gameView = findViewByID(R.id.your_gameview_id)`

Answer (score 0):

You didn't define gameView variable.
You should put
`gameView = findeVideById(R.id.game_view)`
in your onCreate method